# Select Query Issue MYSQL

Tags: mysql

This query is fetching 1000 records:

```
select * from xyz where abc=3 and qwe in (employee_ids)
```

This query is fetching 1408 as count:

```
select count(*) from xyz where abc=3 and qwe  in (employee_ids)

select * from xyz where abc=3 and qwe in (employee_ids) -- 1000
select count(*) from xyz where abc=3 and qwe  in (employee_ids) -- 1408
```

Comment: Getting exact 1000 records means you seem to have an inherent `LIMIT 1000` clause getting applied somewhere. Are you checking this in PhpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench ?

Comment: You're testing it in a phpmyadmin? becouse maybe you have it separated by pages (1000 rows per page)... so, go to the next page!

Comment: SELECT* from xyz where abc=3 and qwe in (employee_ids) LIMIT 1,(select count(*) from xyz where abc=3 and qwe  in (employee_ids));

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a useful question. Whatever client you're using obviously has a 1000 row limit. In the future, ask your question more clearly.